# Updating a global variable from inside a function called by setInterval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a variable every 1000 milliseconds in a function using `setInterval`. It's not working and I know it's a scope issue. 
I can find a solution that works for me - console logging outside of the function does not happen at the predetermined interval.

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

```
const interval = 1000;
setInterval(function({
  myFunc(`${duration._data.minutes}:${duration._data.seconds}`)}, 
interval);

function myFunc(vari) {
  duration = moment.duration(duration.asMilliseconds() - interval, 'milliseconds');
  countdown = vari;
}

console.log(countdown);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect. The function you pass to `setInterval()` will be called over and over again, once every second. The `console.log()` *outside* the function will just happen once, and it will happen immediately after the initial call to `setInterval()`, before the callback has happened. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, `countdown` is declared earlier in the global scope. What I want to do is update `countdown` every second and have it available in the global scope after update

Comment: Yes, can you tell us what you are trying to do with this?

Comment: You can certainly update the variable inside the callback, but the callback (and the update) will happen at its own pace. If you want to do something with the updated value, the only way to make it happen at the exact point that the update is done is to do that work *inside* the callback function.

Comment: Thanks @Compilerv2 I'm trying to update variable `countdown` using setInterval and have it available in the global scope

Comment: Once it's "available in the global scope", what do you plan to do with it? How do you expect the global scope to "know" each time the update has occurred?

Comment: @tommmmmmmy, put a console.log(countdown) right after countdown = vari within myFunc. It will show that the global is actually updated.

Comment: @tommmmmmmy if you want to inform entities in your application about some variable changing its value, consider using the [publish-subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log(countdown) need to be inside the function myFunc, then the console.log will show every interval!

You should create a variable `var duration;` before use it, because if you create duration as a const, then wont work!

pay attention on the console errors!